# PreSaveAction is not firing

Tags: javascript

Any idea why the PreSaveAction is not firing. I am trying to take the user to a thankyou page when they complete a survey. I added this js thru SP Designer to NewForm.aspx.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="'/_layouts/jQuery/jquery-1.6.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
// old handler:
var buttonID = document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_f46a290b_d993_4347_a2da_868aff18de82_ctl00_toolBarTbltop_RightRptControls_ctl01_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem");
var oldHandler = function() {
if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00_m_g_f46a290b_d993_4347_a2da_868aff18de82_ctl00_toolBarTbltop_RightRptControls_ctl01_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem", "", true, "", "", false, true));
};
// remove old and add new handler:
var newHandler = function() {
if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;

<input type="button" value="Finish" name="Submit" onclick="if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;{ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={/thankyou.aspx}');}" />

//WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00_m_g_f46a290b_d993_4347_a2da_868aff18de82_ctl00_toolBarTbltop_RightRptControls_ctl01_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem", "", true, "", "", false, true));
//window.location.replace("/ThankYou.aspx");
return true;
};
$("#ctl00_m_g_f46a290b_d993_4347_a2da_868aff18de82_ctl00_toolBarTbltop_RightRptControls_ctl01_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem").unbind("click", oldHandler).click(newHandler);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={../../Pages/SurveyWirelessThankYou.aspx}')}
```

I tried this steps from this link (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-BE/sharepoint2010general/thread/77009cb5-4951-427d-8c23-5a75aff74290) and it seems to work. This steps put the above java-script code on the button (click event)

1. Open survey in SPD, in the page to view and manage setting for the list, click New button on Forms section;
2. Enter the filename and select "New item form" as the selected type of form. Check "Set as default form for the selected type". Choose "survey" as the content type
3. Click "OK" and a new form is created.
4. Open the custom form, delete the default “Finish” button.
5. Select “Insert” menu at the top of the page>select “SharePoint” from the ribbon>select “Form Action Button” from the SharePoint controls.
6. In the Form Actions, select  the two actions “Commit” and “Navigate to page”
7. Select the “Navigate to page” action, click “settings” to set the target page : http://sharepoint/pages/thankyou.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to craft a hyperlink to the NewForm page that includes a ?Source querystring parameter to the page you want to end up.  The hyperlink could be modified by a jQuery script to append the query string parameter.  I have an example of that I will try to dig up as a reference.

```
http://sharepoint.mycompany.com/sites/mysite/lists/survey/NewForm.aspx?Source=http://http://sharepoint.mycompany.com/sites/mysite/Lists/survey/ThankYou.aspx
```

Edit: Here's the [link](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/STP/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=2143&hilit=Append%20Source) to the jQuery I was refering to.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a[href*='NewForm.aspx']").click(function(){
      var curr_URL = document.location.href;
      appendTo_URL = "?Source=" + curr_URL;
      var link_URL = $(this).attr('href');
                //alert(link_URL + appendTo_URL);
      $(this).attr('href', link_URL + appendTo_URL);
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: new form's url looks like this http://portal/surveys/Lists/TestSurvey/NewForm.aspx?IsDlg=1 ; my var curr_URL='/pages/ThankYou.aspx'; records is added but redirection is not working.

Comment: I opened the IE developer tool and it's chocking on $(document).ready(function(){ line, stating "object expected" character 1

Comment: Do I need to add a reference to jQuery? or it's a normal javascript?

Comment: It's jQuery, I believe it was from the 1.3 days but it still works on 1.6.

Comment: Okay, I added <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> but redirection piece is still not working. (adding to survey works)

Comment: I am confused. Should the new form url be with the source= url. instead it's http://portal/surveys/Lists/TestSurvey/NewForm.aspx?IsDlg=1

Comment: This script is from a 2007 site and it assumes that on the quick launch there is a link to the new item form for the survey.  Let me try it in a Foundations site and see how it behaves.

Comment: @Eric: Thank you Eric. You may be 100% right. Please let me know your findings and if you discover any tweak that fixes the issue.

Comment: I tried putting this inside the head section of the master page (v4). <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/jquery/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script> but no redirection yet.

Comment: I haven't gotten the script to work yet.  When I hardcode the source into the Quick launch item or as a hyperlink on my page with the ?Source parameter it works successfully.  When I include the IsDlg parameter it doesn't work right.  I'm still on 2007 so the dialogs are new to me.  I'm not sure how to work around that at the moment.

Comment: I registered js in masterpage per this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yojoshi/archive/2010/06/17/using-jquery-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx but no luck yet.