# redirecting to another page when item is added to a list

Tags: redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PreSaveAction is not firing](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18725/presaveaction-is-not-firing)

This code only adds item but not doing the redirecting....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var button = $("input[id$=ctl00$m$g_f46a290b_d993_4347_a2da_868aff18de82$ctl00$toolBarTbltop$RightRptControls$ctl01$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem]");
    // change redirection behavior
        button.removeAttr("onclick");
        button.click(function() {
            var elementName = $(this).attr("Finish");
            var aspForm = $("form[name=aspnetForm]");
            var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.get(0).action;
            var currentSourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldPostbackUrl);
            var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue, "/srv/Pages/ThankYou.html");

            if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
            WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true));
        });

});
</script>
```

Comment: @Nancy, If you have made updates, please edit your original post instead of posting a new question. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to craft a hyperlink to the NewForm page that includes a ?Source querystring parameter to the page you want to end up.

```
http://sharepoint.mycompany.com/sites/mysite/lists/survey/NewForm.aspx?Source=http://http://sharepoint.mycompany.com/sites/mysite/Lists/survey/ThankYou.aspx
```